# std::sort on empty vector

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector

Is `std::sort` supposed to work correctly if it gets an empty range?

I get a segmentation fault (gcc 4.8.3) for this code:

```
std::vector<float> f;
std::sort( f.begin() + 1, f.end() );
```

Standard says that for an empty vector `begin()` and `end()` return same value. So I expected `sort` to do nothing in the case above because it should get an empty range: `begin()+1` should be greater than `end()`.

There is no problem for this empty range sort:

```
std::sort( f.begin(), f.end() );
```

Comment: And what about `f.begin() + 1`? Wouldn't that be out of bounds?

Comment: @juanchopanza It is some value, what matters is that `begin() + 1` is > `end()`.

Comment: It is some value that is an invalid iterator. It is not `>` or `<` than `end()`. It is just invalid.

Comment: @user2052436, It is undefined behaviour. In an empty range, `begin() == end()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f.begin()+1` is out of bounds and that is the reason for the segmentation fault.

Use `f.begin()` for the beginning of the array.And that will be safe to use.

Comment: Ok, so to sort excluding first element, I need to check `size() > 0` before calling `sort`.

Answer (score 6):

`std::sort` expects the `[begin, end)` to be a valid range such that if you keep incrementing `begin` you would eventually reach the `end`. In your case, `begin()+1` is past the `end()`, so `std::sort` has no way of knowing that it is looking past the end of the range.

`std::sort` takes iterators, not pointers. It is because of this that it is unable to run a `begin < end` check: this would fail if you passed `rbegin()` and `rend()` for the two iterators.

If you would like to sort a portion of the `std::vector` that excludes the initial element, you need to make sure that the container is not empty. Otherwise, `begin()+1` would produce an invalid iterator.

Note: although technically the undefined behavior takes place when you do `begin()+1` on an empty container, the crash in your case is nearly certainly coming from a dereference inside `std::sort`. Also note that if you have a C++11-compliant compiler, using `std::next(v.begin(), 1)` is preferable to `v.begin() + 1`.

Comment: You don't get to std::sort, it's all over earlier.

Comment: Ok, now you call out the actual error as well, I reversed my vote.

Answer (score 3):

Increment on input iterators has a *precondition* that the iterator must be *dereferenceable*. With an empty vector, `v.begin()` is not dereferenceable so attempting to do `v.begin() + 1` (which in turn is defined in terms of increment) is undefined behavior.

Moreover, `std::sort(begin, end)` requires `[begin, end)` to be a valid range, and the standard says  that (§24.2.1 [iterator.requirements.general]/p7)

> Range `[i,j)` is valid if and only if `j` is reachable from `i`. The result of the application of functions in the library to invalid ranges is undefined.

For most random access iterators (the only type of iterators for which `<` and `>` are defined), if `a > b` then `a` is not reachable from `b`, and so `[a, b)` does *not* denote the empty range - it doesn't denote a valid range at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator ...that's the first paragraph?

Comment: @Deduplicator UB doesn't always show up directly. Here, the segfault probably originates from `it != end`, so dereferencing `begin + 1` (which points to invalid memory, yes) will happen, so boom. Yes, technically the program exhibits UB at `v.begin() + 1`, but the rest is important too.

Comment: @Deduplicator The reason why `v.begin() + 1` is undefined behavior is precisely because `v.begin()` is not dereferenceable and you have a precondition violation.